# How to use marked and sanitize html instead of sending raw html to front end

Tags: javascript, node.js, javascript-marked

I'm using marked, dompurify, and JSDOM to convert markedown text to HTML and then sanitize but It sends send raw HTML instead of HTML

imports

```
const { marked } = require("marked");
const createDomPurify = require("dompurify");
const { JSDOM } = require("jsdom");
const dompurify = createDomPurify(new JSDOM().window);
```

```
const sanitizedArticle = dompurify.sanitize(marked(news.article));
```

input

```
# Lorem ipsum dolor,
```

output

```
<h1 id="lorem-ipsum-dolor">Lorem ipsum dolor,</h1>
```

Comment: I'm using the latest version: 5.1.1